# Use databinding with the ToolBarTray control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I’m working on a WPF/PRISM app. I started by creating a dynamic menu using databinding following that example: http://www.koaxkoaxkoax.com/ribbit/2010/09/creating-dynamic-menus-in-wpf.html
It uses a **HierarchicalDataTemplate** which seems like a nice solution.

I had the goal to use the same concept for toolbars but sadly the **ToolBarTray** control doesn’t have a **ItemsSource** to dynamically generate Toolbar controls in it.

I’m pretty new to WPF and I can’t seem to find a good solution to create toolbars inside a ToolBarTray using **databinding**. Does somebody have a solution?

Is it possible with **HierarchicalDataTemplate**?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

While the ToolBarTray does not contain an ItemsSource property, it does contain a ToolBars property that you'd be able to bind to.  And then, each ToolBar has an ItemsSource property that you could bind to as well.

So your binding would look something like this:

```
<ToolBarTray ToolBars="{Binding MyToolBarsProperty}" />
```

Then you could start using HierarchicalDataTemplates on the Toolbars:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    </Style>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Sadly that is not possible either because the ToolBars property has only a getter (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbartray.toolbars(v=vs.110).aspx)